# Decomposition of Wave function in infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am given that a wave function at time 0 is given as
$$\psi(x,t=0)=\sin^6(\frac{\pi x}{2L})\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2L})$$
I am asked to find this wave function as a function of time.  In order to do this, I feel like I need to find the combinations of eigenfunctions that make this function and then I can find how they each evolvewith time, so that
$$\psi(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$$

Am I correct in saying this?  I feel that this makes sense, and then I can find $c_n$ as $$c_n=\int_0^{2L}\psi(x,t=0)\sin(\frac{n\pi
 x}{2L})dx$$

Answer (score 1):

That's all fine except, that you need properly normalized eigenfunctions to calculated the $c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you are correct in the approach.However,the $c_n$ must be appropriately normalized.

$$c_n=\frac{1}{L}\int_0^{2L}\psi(x,t=0)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{2L})dx$$